# select is not saving file descriptors

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Yesterday I discovered `select`, which is a very useful tool, but I'm not able to make it work. This is part of my total code:

```
/* Code here */
FD_ZERO(&fifo_set);
printf("%d\n", num_proc);
for(i = 0; i < num_proc; ++i)
    FD_SET(proc[i].fifowfd, &fifo_set);

/* More code here */
while(1)
{
    if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &fifo_set, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    {
        log_event(5, "Could not block.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("FD_SETSIZE: %d\n", FD_SETSIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i)
        printf("ISSET %d: %d\n", i, FD_ISSET(i,&fifo_set));

    log_event(1, "Actions to be done.");
/* More code */
```

The array proc, is an array of processes, given its PID, and a read and write FIFO. The file descriptors to the FIFOs are checked, and are valid.
The problem is: there are 3 processes (num_proc), with the fifowfd values 5, 7 and 9. But when I print all FD_ISSET, only the 5 seems to be registered and have data, but all three have data. FD_SETSIZE has the value 1024.

As @mux pointed, this FIFOs are named like "FIFO for writing". The thing is, that I have a bunch of "name.r.fifo" and "name.w.fifo", which represent "FIFO for reading/writing" from the side of the process. The code I'm showing, is the code from the controller, which reads in the ".w.fifo", and writes to the ".r.fifo".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `select()` is the highest-numbered file descriptor plus 1:

```
select(highest_fd+1, &fifo_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Note: the fd set will contain the descriptors that are "ready" after select returns, you should set the fds again if you want to do another `select()`

Comment: Bad explained: there are FIFOs for each process, named "name.r.fifo" and "name.w.fifo", used for read and write from the process side. This code I'm showing, is the controller, that reads where the process writes.

Comment: @markmb oh, I see.. then try to pass the highest fd see if it fixes the problem

Comment: @markmb see my note, you need to add the fds again before each call to select, because after it returns the set is modified to include the fds that have changed their state.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your note. This was the mistake. As there was data first in number 5, and then in 7 and 9, when it looped, only looked at 5. Thank you very much! I lost all the morning with this.

Answer (score 2):

If all descriptors have no data when select is called, it will block until at least one descriptor is ready for reading. Probably, descriptor 5 is the first one to be checked and select exits before other pipes have any data to read.

You should also check the actual result of select since it contains number of bits it set.

Comment: I forgot to add the while(1) loop in this code. The select is at the start of a while(1) loop, and when select returns, is because there's data in FIFO number 5, not because of the others.

Comment: As well as this, select always returns 1, and, as said, only returns when there's data in number 5, not in 7 neither 9.